# Should my Twilio number be able to receive SMS from any number (in my country)?

Tags: twilio

I've set up a Twilio number. It is SMS capable.

When I send SMS to it from my own number (registered with Twilio), Twilio receives the SMS and forwards it as required.

When I SMS it from *another* number, the message appears to be sent OK (no error message to say it hasn't been delivered), but then nothing happens. Twilio doesn't receive the message. It's the same phone company. I send from an iPhone, both with iMessage turned on and with it turned off.

I may be missing something very obvious. Nothing in Twilio's help covers this. I'm not on a trial account, I've paid for a full account.

Comment: Is the sim card already activated? Might be that if it's not it's only capable of receiving network internal SMS.

Comment: @Dominik Twilio is an SMS provider, not a cellular service. There's no SIM card involved on their end of the service.

Comment: Are you able to send an SMS from Twilio to that other number?